# Поиск значения в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Приветствую! Возникла проблемка. Есть массив array()
    `[0] => 123
    [1] => orange
    [2] => apple
    [3] ...`

```
и в нем например 50000 значений. 
Нужно найти в нем значение Apple и вернуть его ключ.
```

Есть ли функции по типу in_array только что бы вернули ключ?
 Попробовал функцию array_search но она проходит как я понял по всему массиву и занимает много времени а in_array как я понял проверяет и занимает на много меньше времени. Так как так сделать что бы нашло Apple и вернуло его ключ?

Comment: Можно просто написать прохождение по массиву и сравнивание значения с "apple", заканчивать работу цикла, когда значение найдено.

Comment: Не все так просто, много времени это займет. Я так раньше и сделал.
Если например уже будет нужно найти сначала apple а потом orange то оно прогонит весь массив на apple а потом на orange а это уже много времени занимает а если бы как то сразу обратится как в in_array то получилось бы что оно проверяет существует ли и берет ключ и не тратит время на его перебор.

Comment: всё равно in_array проходит по всему массиву так же и ищет. Можно условие написать, которое будет объединять нужные значения

Comment: @Богдан, тест https://gist.github.com/ksimka/21a6ff74b41451c430e8 и комментарий там в самом низу.

Comment: @Visman, Благодарю, очень похоже на то что мне нужно

Comment: А как этот массив формируется? А могут ли в нем быть дубли? Если там хранятся простые строки, почему бы их не сделать ключами? isset($array[$key]) достаточно быстро отрабатывает. А в качестве значения можно хранить интересующий показатель или что еще в зависимости от контекста задачи

Comment: @AndreiGuba Так и сделал с помощью array_flip перевернул массив и проверял сразу значение через isset способ раньше занимал по 5 минут а теперь ускорилось все до 10-15 секнуд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"функция типа in_array только чтобы возвращала ключ" - это **array_search()**

Однако не надо воображать, будто встроенная функция будет выполнять поиск каким-то особым магическим способом, и делать это быстрее, чем перебор в цикле, написанный вручную. Эти функции будут искать точно так же перебором, что для  массива такого объема будет очень неэффективно.

поэтому в первую очередь следует постараться избежать такого поиска совсем. Например записав данные в БД, и делая запросы на поиск уже к ней.

Или представив массив в другой форме, например записав значения в качестве ключей в другой массив. Это сработает, если в массиве нет дублирующихся значений.

В любом случае, конкретное решение зависит от деталей конкретной задачи.

Comment: Функции стандартной библиотеки PHP, в т.ч. и array_search() быстрее вручную написанного перебора, так как они выполняются на низком уровне.
Сравнение использования функций array_search, in_array и техники с заменой ключей значениями можно изучить здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518404/which-is-best-array-search-or-in-array

Comment: 1. Не надо пересказывать байки про "низкий уровень". неоптимальный алгоритм на любом уровне останется неоптимальным. 2. По ссылке про ручной перебор ничего нет. 3. даже если бы и было, то  чудовищные способы измерения производительности применяемые несчастными похапешниками в любом случае не имеют никакого отношения к реальной жизни

Comment: Если алгоритм требует поиска значения в массиве - значит, так надо с точки зрения бизнес-логики. Предложенная вами альтернатива с ключами нарушает логику программы, будучи спорным костылем + уникальность значений может не быть гарантирована.
Альтернатива с записью в БД - полное нарушение логики разделения обязанностей + крах производительности, т.к. взаимодействие с БД и последующая обработка данных не дешевле, чем поиск по массиву.

Comment: @DmitryNevzorov все эти досужие рассуждения - полное фуфло, если используются для оправдания поиска перебором по массиву в 50к записей.